# Using chisel3 with namespacing mechanism?

Tags: chisel

I used chisel3 to generate verilog and to cooperate with other verilog coder.

When it is a big project, there will be module name conflicting.
For example, the generated verilog might have a module called **Queue** or **Arbiter**, which is a widely used name.

I wonder if there is any machanism like c++'s namespace to resolve name conflicting?

Comment: This is a great question and  needed feature. Unfortunately no existing API for this. If you would like to comment on the open-issue for such a feature, it could help encourage the developers to prioritize such a feature: https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/issues/1059